# Android architecture auth and api layer with token

Tags: android, mvvm, architecture, authorization, token

I'm currently stucked planning my architecture (MVVM) and flow for the next app.

I want the User to tap 'log in' button to get token from api. Then token is used to authorize some of api calls. 
I'd like to store token in `AuthService` (singleton) class, but to do that I have to inject my `ApiService` (singleton) to `AuthService` to make first login request. 
Then I need the token back in `ApiService` injected from `AuthService` to be able to make authorized requests. The problem is that both `ApiService` and `AuthService` depend on each other (I'd like to avoid creating another Volley instance in `AuthService` just to make one-time get token request - prefer making requests using ApiService only).

The qestion is... how should I go with it? What is the pro-way of solving problem like this one?
Any hints much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a shared preference provider in your dependency injection tree, and have a method in it that stores/retrieve the user token. Then you can inject the shared preference in your repository, and in your repository, you will have the ApiService which you can pass the token to from the injected shared preference instance.

Comment: Thanks Alaa. 
SharedPreferences are not the recommended way to store tokens and user data due to root access, that's why I prefer to keep it 'in memory' (in AuthService). But you've just opened my mind that there shuld be another TokenProvider that will get token using ApiService, then provide it to AuthService. That way ApiService will have AuthService instance and will be able to get token from there.
I knew its was easy but somehow missed it... LOL :D. Thanks and have a good day!